# VBA Macro to insert Average in the last row of each column with dynamic ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I have a number of columns (in Excel file) that represent months of the year; each column has a number of records and I'd like to be able to run a macro that would insert a cell in the last row of each column with an Average. The first cell of each column is a header, so I need to be including cells from row 2 down to the last record in the column. The number of columns and rows will be different each time i use the macro . I would very much appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: This has been answered here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14887210/excel-vba-calculate-average-of-a-column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that will work out of the box for you. It takes the average of each column, starting at row 2.

```
Sub AverageColumn()
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim sum As Integer
    Dim lastCol As Integer
    lastCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.count).Column
    For c = 1 To lastCol
        sum = 0
        count = 0
        ActiveSheet.Cells(2, c).Select
        Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
            sum = sum + ActiveCell.Value
            count = count + 1
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
        Loop
        ActiveCell.Value = sum / count
    Next c
End Sub
```